# How to setup multiple websites and use language code in url

Tags: magento-1.8

There are 3 websites with 2 languages for each of them.

- www.site1.com/en
- www.site1.com/fr
- www.site2.com/en
- www.site2.com/fr
- www.site3.com/en
- www.site3.com/fr

How to setup the `system/configuration`, `index.php`, `.htaccess` and `apache conf`?

Answer (score 0):

To append store Codes to url you just need to go to

```
System->Configuration->Web->Url Options->Add Store Code to Urls
```

**Set it to yes**

and done .. store codes will be added to the urls.

Enjoy.